# Mockito inject/mock multiple services

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, mockito

I am testing my Spring Boot Services.

I have a `ServiceA` with a Spring `RepositoryA` and a `ServiceB` with `RepositoryB`.

Also I have `ClassA` > 1:n >`ClassB` (`ClassA` owns `ClassB`. `ClassB` has no reference to `ClassA`).

In my test I need to add `ClassB` to `ClassA` and then save `ClassA` with its service.

Then I have to test a method of `ServiceB` which internally calls a `void`-method. For that I need a persisted `ClassB` because the `void`-method in the `RepositoryA` tests for "EntityNotFound" and throws an Exception which causes the test to fail.

So I need to use `ServiceA` in my `ServiceBTest.java` to persist a `ClassA` whom `ClassB` I need to use.

I am testing with Mockito so I tried to inject both Services with `@InjectMocks` and `@Mock`. But that doesnt work. If I do that, NOTHING works correctly.

```
@InjectMocks
private ServiceA serviceA;

@InjectMocks
private ServiceB serviceB;

@Mock
private RepositoryA repoA;

@Mock
private RepositoryB repoB;


@Before
public void initMocks() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

Anyone could help me how to get that done?

For no I replaced the repository and service of `B` with inner "Testable" classes in my ClassBTest.java. But the problem is that the Code Coverage is not increasing on the original class.

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
C c = new C();
b.addC(c);
a.addB(b)

serviceA.update(a); //must be "persisted" to persist b as well

   C cEmpty = new C();

Mockito.when(serviceB.update(Mockito.any(B.class))).thenReturn(cEmpty); // plain object to compare with

serviceB.removeCFromB(b, c); // 1. -> remove 2.-> update 2.1 -> checkEntityNotFound

C result = serviceB.findC(a, b, 0);

Assert.assertNull(result);
```

Comment: Do it manually? The annotations are nice, but they are not a dependency injection framework.

Comment: This is unclear. Can you post a [mcve] (even if not working) and explain what do you expect

Comment: I added the test